# How to repair Windows Bootmanager after formatting boot-loader partition during Linux Installation?

Tags: linux, partition, windows, dual-boot, boot-loader

Due to a GPU upgrade, today I reinstalled my Linux (Pop_!OS with nvidia driver) on my dual boot configuration alongside Windows 10. It is a GPT style NVMe disk.
Doing so, I think that I accidentally formatted my windows bootloader partition. I guess I have reinstalled Linux in UEFI mode alongside Legacy Windows Installation. Will I be able to fix my dilemma somehow?
Right now I am pretty messed and I would like to repair/rebuild a functioning Bootloader, which recognized my Linux Distro and Windows 10.

Mainly I need to rescue my Windows Installation, since my Linux Homefolder has its own Partition, so reinstalling Linux is no Problem. But since corona lockdown-distance-elearning I have pretty much to lose on that current Windows Installation. Please Help me. >_>

What I tried in Linux so far:

- `update-grub` -> does not detect windows partition
- `os-prober` -> Shows no output
- `sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub-common grub-efi-amd64 os-prober` -> did not help
- `boot-repair` -> from live distro --> detects legacy windows installation but fails to repair

What I tried with Windows Stick:

- `fixrec /fixmbr` -> prints successful
- `fixrec /fixboot` -> prints some error (access denied iirc)
- `fixrec /rebuildbcd` -> detects windows installation -> then after confirm to rebuild that installation -> "Path no found"
- Automatic Repair Option does not succeed

Please, has someone a helping thought on my dilemma?!

[image]

Comment: You have a Microsoft reserved at p4, your Windows is an UEFI install if gpt partitioned. If running Windows repairs, be sure to boot repair/recovery flash drive in UEFI boot mode. Did you install Windows after Ubuntu, as normally Windows has lower numbered partitions.  How you boot install/repair media for both Ubuntu & Windows is then how it repairs. Use Boot-Repair ppa with Ubuntu live installer.
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run autofix until reviewed by someone.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair